# Show shortcode without executing it

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to display code in my WordPress page and it isn't working. Everything I read says that you should be able to just use `pre` tag with code tag and it would be good but when I try to display a shortcode, it renders the shortcode rather than displaying the code.

The codex says that using `pre` and code would work but it isn't for me. Has anyone had this issue? Am I missing something in `functions.php` that makes this work?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To display a shortcode instead of rendering it you have two options:

1. Write `[[shortcode]]`. WordPress will show this as `[shortcode]`.
2. Escape the `[`, write it as as `&#x5b;` or `&#91;`.

Comment: Hi, mmy problem with the `&#91;`shortcode`&#93;` is that each time I edit the page they are changed to brackets characters..BTW, the 1st solution works fine for me

Comment: If you have a shorcode with content, put the extra brackets around the whole shortcode, not the beginning and end tags, ie `[[shortcode]content goes here[/shortcode]]`

Answer (score 4):

Using `&#91` tag will not work if you switch between the text and visual editor.

The `[[shortcode]]` solution does not work either with WP 4.1.1.

Instead, the following solution works:

```
[[shortcode]
Hello World
[/shortcode]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me: 
`&#91;shortcode&#93;` where `&#91` is [ and `&#93;` is ] html codes.

Don't worked for me the one suggested by toscho:
*Write [[shortcode]]. WordPress will show this as [shortcode].*

Answer (score 3):

I tried all suggested answers, none worked for me.

Here is my (strange) way of showing **[solr_search_shortcode]**:
`<pre>[<code>solr_search_shortcode</code>]</pre>`

See it live [here](https://www.wpsolr.com/knowledgebase/is-there-a-shortcode-to-display-the-ajax-search-where-i-need/).

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping brackets with `<span>[</span>` also seems to work