# Shortcode interpreted as text

Tags: categories, shortcode

I have the following shortcode in one of my pages

```
[[Intern: Termine/News]]
```

This works on a password protected sub page. Now I want that all news of the category Termine/News are on the parent page. So I put the code on the password protected parent page. Now the text is rendered - I only can see the shortcode text. But I should see all the articles!

What is wrong? Or do I missunderstanding something?

Edit:

Figured it out. There was some code directly in the template and so the content in the WP backend was totally ignored. Added the code in the template php file and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid syntax. See shortcodes like HTML:

- Opening delimiter `[`,
- name `intern`,
- empty space,
- attribute name,
- equal sign `=`,
- attribute value (enclosed with quotes (`'` or `"`),
- closing delimiter `]`.

Doubled delimiters force the shortcode to be shown as it is, the shortcode handler [will not be used](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/64616/73).

`[[Intern: Termine/News]]` is wrong, you need probably `[intern type="Termine/News"]`.

See the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The usual format for short codes is `[tag var='foo'/]`. I'm not really clear on what your tag is, but I'd expect something more like this would work as you desire: `[yourtag intern='Termine/News' /]`