# Change the default video URL in a post to shortcode format

Tags: posts, shortcode, urls

I want to add video from youtube/vimeo  to my post.Whenever i add a video to my post ,there will  display a link like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsUXAEzaC3Q in my admin(Add new post ),and in the front end it will display the video.But the problem is, i want to show the video like a shortcode example 
[video url=”https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsUXAEzaC3Q”][/video]in the place of original video.That is show the shortcode like above  instead of the video in front end.How can it possible.Please help me.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly … do you mean [Show shortcode without executing it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64615/show-shortcode-without-executing-it)?

Comment: when click on the shortcode it should display the video.

Comment: Youtube is already supported as part of the [embed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) functionality along with various other popular video sites.

Answer (score 0):

To render the shortcode output with a clickable link while it still looks like a shortcode, you have to replace the built-in shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'video', 'wpse_96840_literal_video' );

function wpse_96840_literal_video( $atts )
{
    $url = $atts['url'];

    return '<code>'
        . sprintf( '[video url="<a href=\"%1$s\">%1$s</a>"][/video]', $url )
        . '</code>';
}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: The built-in shortcode is not yet in WordPress. It will come in version 3.6. As to where to put this code: [use a custom plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code at the end of the `functions.php` file and you have to replace the built-in shortcode.

```
function video_shortcode($atts) {
    // Extract the URL from the shortcode attributes
    $url = isset($atts['url']) ? esc_url($atts['url']) : '';

    // Check if a valid URL is provided
    if ($url) {
        // Extract the video ID from the YouTube URL
    $video_id = '';
    parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query_params);
    if (isset($query_params['v'])) {
        $video_id = $query_params['v'];
    }

    // If video ID found, generate the iframe code for embedding YouTube video
    if ($video_id) {
        $iframe_code = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $video_id . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        return $iframe_code;
    }
    }

    // If no valid URL is provided, return an empty string
    return '';
}
add_shortcode('custom_video', 'video_shortcode');
```