# How to print [embed] code in wordpress

Tags: shortcode, tinymce

I would like to print the following code in wordpress.

```
[embed]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0[/embed]
```

But every time I use that code in the wordpress editor, it automatically embeds the video. Is there a way to print it.

I've tried `pre` and the answer mentioned here

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/64616/5074

But its still not working.

Comment: Doubling brackets doesn't work (probably because embeds are not processed like normal shortcodes), but encoding bracket tested and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special trick to do that with simple shortcode like [gallery]:

`[[gallery]]`

But I do not know if it works with enclosed shorcodes

EDIT: I guess you have to use solution 2 provided by toscho

> write it as as `&#x5b;` or `&#91;`;

If you have to write it from time to time you could use the [Quicktags API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Quicktags_API)